# How to have file and directory dialog in same window in PyQt5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

For now i have two scripts one for file dialog and one of directory dialog. I want to have same option in one scripts in pyqt5. How can i do that?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
def hello():
    app=QApplication(sys.argv)
    w=QWidget()
    w.resize(1100,800)
    b=QPushButton(w)
    b.move(10,30)
    b.clicked.connect(on_click_me)
    b.setText("Add_Files")
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
def on_click_me():
    dialog=QFileDialog()
    #dialog.setFileMode(QFileDialog.Directory);
    #dialog.setFileMode(QFileDialog.AnyFile);
    dialog.exec_()
    #print(fileName)

hello()
```

Like this code will allow me to select either files or directory depending upon `QFileDialog.Directory` or `QFileDialog.AnyFile` method. Can't i can create something so i can open whatever i want directory or file at the selection time.

Comment: Your question is confusing, you could show your code and explain what you want based on it.

Comment: Added some details, hope it make some sense now @eyllanesc